# Refactoring method with Optional to one line

Tags: java, spring

I have a method in my Service for updating existing organisations.

```
public Optional<Organisation> update(Organisation org) {
    Optional<Organisation> optionalOrganisation = organisationRepository.findById(org.getId());
    if (optionalOrganisation.isPresent()) {
        Organisation organisationToUpdate = optionalOrganisation.get();
        organisationRepository.save(organisationToUpdate);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

How to refactor this method to one line?

It should be something like this:

```
public Optional<Organisation> update(Organisation org) {
    return organisationRepository.findById(org.getId()) // what should be here?
```

Comment: Why does your method always return `Optional.empty()` ?

Comment: Why would you (re)save (`organisationRepository.save(organisationToUpdate);`) an `Organization` you just retrieved (with no updates made to it), I wonder.

Comment: BTW why the method returning Optional.empty()? Anyway you can do something like `organisationRepository.findById(org.getId()).ifPresent(org -> organisationRepository.save(org));`

Comment: If you only want to do something when there is a value, and do nothing otherwise, [Optional.ifPresent()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)) will be of interest to you. If you want to use a new/default value in the case a value is absent from the repository, then you should look into the family of methods starting with `Optional.or`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
public Optional<Organisation> update(Organisation org) {
    return organisationRepository.findById(org.getId())
            .map(organisationRepository::save);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Optional<Organisation> optionalOrganisation = organisationRepository.findById(org.getId())

optionalOrganisation.ifPresent(o -> { 
//update your object
} )

return optionalOrganisation;
```

You don't need save it will be automaticaly if it's Transaction